# Was absence of mention about brAhmanas, upanishads, aranyakas in Ramayana indicates that it had been composed much earlier to them?

Tags: vedas, ramayana, upanishads, brahmanas, aranyaka

I tried to find any mention of  **brAhmanas, upanishads, aranyakas** in Ramayana, as they were supposed to have been composed in post vedic period, as Ramayana was.

The following slokas are from 5th Sarga of Bala Kanda of Valmiki Ramayana.

> तामग्निमद्भिर्गुणवद्भिरावृताम् द्विजोत्तमैः ***वेदषडङ्गपारगैः*** | सहस्रदैः
> सत्यरतैर्महात्मभिः महर्षिकल्पैः ऋषिभिश्च केवलैः || १-५-२३
>
> She that Ayodhya is encompassed with Vedic scholars who always worship
> the ritual fire by enkindling the three kinds of ritual-fires
> continuously, virtuous Brahman scholars ***in Veda-s and their six
> ancillary subjects***, and other great souls that are in similitude with
> great saints, and who are just like sages that are charitable donors,
> and that abide by the truth.

In the rest of the Ramayana also, no mention of **brAhmanas, upanishads, aranyakas** was found in Ramayana by me.

**Did any one come across such mention?**

If not, can we conclude that Ramayana was composed much earlier to the composition of **brAhmanas, upanishads, aranyakas**?

Comment: what is post-Vedic period ? Ramayana time period is Treta Yuga, which is at least 10 lakh years ago.

Comment: Post vedic period means, when the composition of Veda was over. The veda was composed in Vedic Sanskrit. The brahmanas, aranyakas, upanishads, and epics were composed in Classical Sanskrit. Hence, these were called as composed in post vedic period @ram

Comment: There is a form of Sanskrit linguistically earlier than Vedic Sanskrit attested from around 1500 b.c.in Mitanni - so the Rig Veda we have now is not earlier than 1500 b.c.  Epic Sanskrit is at least a millennium younger than Vedic Sanskrit.  If it was composed a million years ago, natural sound changes would make the attested form completely different from what it was originally.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv, where did you come up with this theory ? what is the dating of "Vedic period" according to you.. sounds like neo-modern fantasy

Comment: Please don't blabber about ""neo-modern fantasy** with me.  I had already explained in my about it using Vedic and classical Sanskrit.  Your knowledge of Veda is limited and still you are trying to brand others with funny names? @ram

Comment: @srimannarayanakv, didn't you recently quote from a book that said Ramayana happened in 7000 B.C or something ? "Your knowledge of Veda is limited" - did you study Vedas at a traditional patashala/gurukula ? Can you chant any of the 5 main suktams/rudram/chamakam ? Do you know what the roles of the 6 vedangas are ?

Comment: Mere chanting of Veda does not make you understand the Veda,my friend:-) . You are  merely chanting a few sentences here and there from the texts you are acquainted with. Your words reminding me with bhajagovindam sloka - **.....nahi nahi rakshati drikunkarane**. @ram. Take my advice my friend. Adopt any of the following options so that you will be happy and others will also be happy.  I am neither good at not interested in arguments. (1/2)

Comment: I know that moderators are with you.  So adopt any of the following options. 1) change the name of this site to Vaishnavism.SE, so that people like me, whom you are branding with funny names like neo-vedantins, will take exit on their own. 2) get my account suspended permanently, with the help of your moderators 3) broaden your vision and understand the world around'you with different perspective, than through the lens you are accustomed to. @ram (2/2)

Comment: @srimannarayanakv, hahaa.. i too have been flagged, and reprimanded by moderators, so you can't hide behind the excuse that i'm being favored.. *"Mere chanting of Veda does not make you understand the Veda,my friend"* - oh, and mere reading of some english books about Vedas, does ? I make no judgement about your knowledge of Vedas. But I definitely do make judgement about someone trying to put wrong dates on Vedas & Itihasas, like 1500 B.C or 7000 B.C or other such nonsense written in some English books.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv, and this is not a vaishnavism, shaivism, shaktism etc. debate. Go ask any smartha vedic scholar if he agrees with your random dates. Many of them are even more vehement about these things than vaishnavas

Comment: Before making allegation upon me that I had stated **recently quote from a book that said Ramayana happened in 7000 B.C or something**, you should have verified the name of the member properly. 
Had it been myself, why will I claim that Ramayana occurred 1.6 million years ago in this question(https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9009/3869)? @ram

Comment: @srimannarayanakv, oh my bad then I apologize for that. But my stance that your definition of "Vedic" period is a modern one doesn't change (until I have scriptural backing to the same, not some western indologist historian drivel). Even 5000 years ago when Vyasa divided Vedas can be called Vedic period. And your classification that brahmanas,upanishads,araynakas don't fall under 'Vedas' is also arbitrary

Comment: How u concluded that Veda means Samhita only?..Why it can't be Samhita, Brahmana, Aranyaka, Upnishada collectively?

Comment: @YDS: I think you have forgotten Puranas to include in the list. :-)

Comment: Puranas comes under 5th Veda :) .. my understanding is that Veda means Samhita, Brahmana, Arnyaka, Upanishada; see [this post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/781/12304) too..so when Ramayana says "यजुः वेद विनीतः" for Rama, I believe it means Samhita, Brahmana, Aranyaka and Upanishads of Yajurveda..

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV  Do not separate Vaishnavism, Saivism etc. This is Hinduism Stack exchange where all hindu gods will be discussed. Pl do not tell that moderators are with Ram. Moderators will not favour anybody. They are not biased.  Quarrel among us will not yield fruitful results.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan: I did not start this argument of  Vaishnavism, Saivism etc. The member (@ram) started calling me **neo-modern**.  I am neither interested in demeaning Vaishnavism, Saivism etc nor in entering into  arguments with anyone.  Coming to the aspect of biased moderators, yes, even today I will stick to my stand.  There is only ONE active moderator in this site, who is biased.  You can check my META posts [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1929/3869) and [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1933/3869), which will explain you, I had concluded so .

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan: The lone moderator is in the habit of deleting many of comments, without giving valid reasons.  So even these comments, addressed to you might be deleted even before you may see them.

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV-- I have not experienced such scenarios. My answers and comments surface when posted.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan:The reason for not experiencing such scenarios might be, according to my guessing, that you belong to the group/sect that majority of the members of this site belong to. :-)

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV  The group is open to all. I do not know who are the moderators. I am just a member contributing what I know. Your guess is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

It would appear so.

There are other references of vedas in Ramayana.

> kushiilavau tu dharmaGYau raajaputrau yashasvinau | bhraatarau
>   svarasampannau dadarsha aashramavaasinau || sa tu medhaavinau
>   dR^ishhTvaa vedeShu pariniShThitau | vedopabR^ihmaNaarthaaya
>   taavagraahayata prabhuh || kaavyaM raamaayaNaM kR^itsnaM
>   siitaayaashcharitaM mahat.h| paulastya vadhamityeva chakaara
>   charitavrataH||
>
> (vAlmIki-rAmAyaNa-bAlakANDa 1.4.5-7)
>
> The princes, the brothers, Kusha and Lava, were knowledgeable about
>   Dharma and were ....skilled in the Vedas, and for the sake of
>   expounding the Vedas, he [Valmiki] composed and made them study the
>   Ramayana..

So, the key is to understand Valmiki composed Ramayana for sake of expounding the Vedas.

First, does the name "rama" occur in the veda ? Yes, it does in Rig Veda. From 10 Mandala, 93 sukta and 14 Rik,

> pra tadduHshIme pR^ithavAne vene pra rAme vochamasure maghavatsu | ye
>   yuktvAya pa.ncha shatAsmayu pathA vishrAvyeshhAm.h ||

nIlakaNTha quotes from the agastya-saMhitA to further support the fact that the rAmAyaNa is drawn from the Vedas:

> vedavedaye pare puMsi jAte dasharathAtmaje | vedaH prAchetasAdAsIt.h
>   sAxAdrAmAyaNAtmanA | tasmAdrAmAyaNaM devi veda eva na saMshayaH ||

nIlakantha also quotes that Valmiki has based the twenty-four thousand verses of the ramayana on the twenty-four syllables of the gayathri mantra. Thus, 1, 1001, 2001 etc. follow the gayathri mantra.He has compiled a list of mantras from the vedas that correspond to the Ramayana. This is known as mantra- rAmAyaNa. One should note that he has written another work based on the correspondence of Rig veda and Srimad Bhagavatam. This is known as mantra-Bhagavata.

five Riks, Rig Veda 10.99.1-5, briefly describe the rAmAyaNa as found in the first few chapters of the vAlmIki rAmAyaNa.

For example,
Rig Veda 10.99.1:

> kaM nashchitramishhaNyasi chikitvAnpR^ithugmAnaM vAshraM
>   vAvR^idhadhyai | kattasya dAtu shavaso vyushhTau taxadvajraM
>   vR^itraturamapinvat.h ||

Rig Veda 10.99.2:

> sa hi dyutA vidyutA veti sAmapR^ithuM yonimasuratvA sasAda | sa
>   sanILebhiH prasahAno asya bhrAturna R^ite saptathasya mAyAH |

Now, the translations of the verses are different in various commentaries.

The interpretation of the verses by sayanacharya is based on the assumption that the samhita portion of karma kanda but there is another interpretation by nilakantha saying these are mantra and not to viewed as karma kanda etc.

Clearly, there is no mention of brAhmanas, upanishads, aranyakas in Ramayana. However, the traditional view such as the Sringeri and Kanchi Kamakoti Maths is that Aranyakas, Brahmanas & Upanishads are part of the respective Vedas. It is just that they were all clubbed under Vedas but later in kali yuga, these texts were split into various categories.

Thus, one can only say that Ramayana was composed based on Rig veda around the same time but before the veda was classified/split into aranyakas, brahmanas etc.

Comment: The language of brAhmanas, upanishads, aranyakas is Classical Sanskrit, whereas the Veda is composed in Vedic Sanskrit.  So brAhmanas, upanishads, aranyakas, cannot be part of the Veda

Comment: Yes, language is different but whether they are part of vedas or not is difficult to answer. Pūrva mīmāṃsakas believe that Vedas were revealed only for the purpose of yajñas because that is what is said by Brahmanas and Pūrva mīmāṃsaka scriptures. This also makes them consider both mantras and brāhmaṇas as Vedas. Uttara mīmāṃsakas consider Upanishads also as part of vedas to give solidity to the philosophies.

Comment: A detailed discussion why they were unlikely in the original vedas is discussed in the book History Of Vedic Literature Brahmana And Aranyaka Works by Dr. Narinder Sharma https://archive.org/details/HistoryOfVedicLiteratureBrahmanaAndAranyakaWorksSShr/mode/2up

Comment: May be. It depends on individual perception

Comment: the words "rama" ans "sita" in rig veda do not refer to rama and sita of Ayodhya https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/32843/rama-and-sita-in-the-vedas

Answer (score 1):

In the Taittirtya Brahmana (1.1.3.5), Prajapati is stated to have assumed the form of a Boar,who lifted up the earth which remained plunged in the water.

> prajapatih  praja  asrjata/  tasamannamupakslyata/
> tabhyassudamupaprabhinat/ tato vai tasamannam nakslyata/yasya
> sudassambharo bhavati/nasya grhe’nnarfi ksiyate/ apo va idamagre
> salilam aslt/ tena prajapatir-asramyata/

In Ayodhya Kanda, similar statement appears:

> स वराहः ततो भूत्वा प्रोज्जहार वसुंधराम् | असृजच् च जगत् सर्वम् सह
> पुत्रैः कृत आत्मभिः || २-११०-४
>
> "Thereafter, that Brahma, assuming the form of boar, caused the earth
> to rise from water and with his sons of pure soul, created the entire
> world."

---

Though mention of brAhmanas, upanishads, aranyakas was not found in Ramayana, the concepts from Taittirtya Brahmana did find place in Ramayana, as mentioned above.

Thus, we can infer that either brAhmanas, upanishads, aranyakas were not mentioned in Ramayana, though they were in existence by then (or) the brAhmanas and Ramayana might have composed at an almost same point of time.